# Old PC used under Ubuntu low graphic mode

Tags: server

I want to disable the GUI for an old PC used for a server in my company to serve an ERP web application. The PC is fairly low spec'ed: P4 3.2 Ghz and 384Mb of RAM

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Ubuntu Server, which I believe doesn't install X (the graphical window system) by default: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server

384MB is acceptable in this case (without X I think you can technically go as low as 192 on a still-supported release) but you'll want to stick to basic LAMP apps.